# IBM MQMFT recommended max monitor per Agent

Tags: ibm-mq

Is there a recommended max number of monitors per agent with IBM MQ MFT? We are on version 9.2.0.2 and are experiencing slow downs when connecting creating/editing monitors on a specific Agent, it has about 100 monitors on it. This agent "heavy hitter" of our 11 agents. Most feed into is and it feeds out to all of them. Just looking for any recommendation or if we should configure an additional agent on the same server. All agents and monitors (150 or so total) are on the same QMGR on an MQ Appliance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every monitor basically runs on it's own thread, hence consume resources. Also remeber, the transfers initiated by each monitor will also run few threads and consume resources. So you may be running lot of concurrent transfers thus agent is possibly getting loaded.

What JVM heap size has been allocated to the agent? Have your tried increasing the JVM heap size? If you see slow downs, it's worth looking at spreading the monitors among multiple agents and as a next step try adding an extra queue manager as well.

Here is a [report](http://ibm-messaging.github.io/mqperf/IBM_MQMFT_9.0.5_Performance_Report_MultipleAgentsPerQueueManager_V2.pdf) that describes the results of tests done on the number of agents connecting to a queue manager.

Comment: Thanks Shashi, We only have 11 Agents may add a few more over time but that's it. In our case one of them is just very busy. I will read the report.